# 18.04 Grub2 splash image not showing. update-grub not detecting splash.png

Tags: grub2, 18.04

I have a splash.png image from my old 5 year linux system that worked on Grub2.

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and I placed the image in `/boot/grub/splash.png`.

I ran `sudo update-grub` and it didn't detect it.

So I added to `/etc/default/grub` the following:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="maybe-ubiquity splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/boot/grub/splash.png"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
GRUB_GFXMODE=1680x1050

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

and I ran `sudo update-grub` and it still did not detect it:

```
one@localhost:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
done
```

Here is my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file http://dpaste.com/33A8MRT

Why isn't my splash image being detected and displayed? When it boots grub only shows the default menu with no splash screen.

Comment: in your /etc/default/grub file, `GRUB_TERMINAL` console mode is disabled. can you enable it by adding # symbol at start. then `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Results with # symbol and without # symbol for `GRUB_TERMINAL` pratap@Satellite:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background: /home/pratap/Downloads/1.png
Found background image: /home/pratap/Downloads/1.png

pratap@Satellite:~$ sudo update-grub
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic

Comment: Thanks for noticing that. I commented it out but it still did not find the image when running `update-grub`

Comment: How did you make it look in your home directory for the image?

Comment: can you share your splash.png file

Comment: I downloaded the image and then gave its location in /etc/default/grub file. There are some limitations for image files.

Comment: Sure, here it is here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FGv2IG4XMMgxCrawf2RfTIRJqEBOMsvy/view?usp=sharing. Thanks for taking the time to try it out. I originally had it names to orange.png but renamed it to splash.png for grub.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link. I will try out now. Meanwhile can you change any other picture which is. jpg and check..

Comment: Hi, I have checked the orange.png file in both 16.04 and 18.04. i did not see any problem. can you change your /boot/grub/splash.png to ~/Downloads folder and see. Or change the any other .jpg file in ~/Downloads.

Comment: Just tried it....no success.

Comment: i have compred your /boot/grub/grub.cfg with my file. i observed that /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme fields are different both of us. can you share your file `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`

Comment: here is my file. https://we.tl/t-FoDHd9YtRy

Comment: Thanks, I tried the orange.png on my xenial laptop grub and it worked with no issues :( Guess it's one of the many bugs in 18.04